# Validação de quantidade de sessões com spring boot e spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2

Preciso validar a quantidade de sessões que possam existir, para que o usuário não consiga logar em dois lugares ao mesmo tempo com as mesmas credenciais. Lendo a documentação do Spring Security e posts, cheguei na implementação abaixo, porem a mesma não funciona.

Alguém já teve problema parecido, ou tem algum outro tipo de validação que eu poderia fazer?

```
 http.sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                .expiredUrl("/entrar")
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
```

Tem um projeto que havia feito para testar a funcionalidade e a classe completa pode ser vista no link abaixo como todas as outras configurações do projeto que foi feito apenas para teste.

https://github.com/MaxwelDev/security/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/security/gp/config/WebSecurityConfig.java

Answer (score 1):

Sua configuração, de acordo com a documentação, parece correta.

Porém, isto pode ser um [problema fora](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45804445/2387977) desta configuração. O Spring, para entender que um mesmo usuário está autenticado mais de uma vez, utiliza os métodos `equals()` e `hashCode()` da sua entidade que representa o usuário (aquela que implementa a interface `UserDetails`).

Faça a implementação correta destes dois métodos, levando em conta apenas as informações que identificam unicamente cada usuário. Provavelmente, a informação a ser usada para isto ó o "login" do usuário.

Exemplo:

```
public class GpUserDetails implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    // código

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof GpUserDetails) {
          return login.equals( ((GpUserDetails) obj).getLogin() );
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return login != null ? login.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```